# Redux not connecting to React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have been playing around with Redux, but I can't seem to get it to connect with React. I am using `connect` with `mapStateToProps` but the props in my store are not being passed into my component. Perhaps somebody could shed some light on why my code won't work? I'm guessing it has something to do with the mapStateToProps function.

Here's the code that I've got:

```
import { connect, Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';`enter code here`


const greetReducer = ( state = '', action ) => {

  if ( action.type === 'greet' ) {

  state = action.greeting

  }

  return state;

};

const runReducer = ( state = '', action ) => {

  if ( action.type === 'run' ) {

    state = action.running

  }

  return state;

};

const reducers = combineReducers({

  greetState: greetReducer,
  runState: runReducer

});

const store = createStore( reducers );

store.dispatch({

  type: 'greet',
  greeting: 'Hello'

});

console.log(store.getState());

store.dispatch({

  type: 'run',
  running: 'Running like the wind'

});

const App = (props) => <h1>{props.greeting}</h1>;

const mapStateToProps = function(store) {
  return {
    greeting: store.getState().greetState
  };
}

connect(mapStateToProps)(App);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `connect` function (or, rather, the function returned by `connect`) does not modify your component; it returns a new component, which you need to save to a variable:

```
const ConnectedApp = connect(mapStateToProps)(App);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}><ConnectedApp /></Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked like a charm. To anyone else that might review this question, another mistake that I made was typing store.getState().greetState - it should just be store.greetState

Comment: @HappyKoala: to clarify, the first argument to `mapState` is _not_ the store object itself.  It is actually the _state_ object in the store.  While the name of the variable itself doesn't matter, the "correct" name would be `state`, so the example would be `state.greetState`.

Comment: @markerikson Thanks, that clarifies it further. If only the world was a JavaScript application  and Dan Abramov was its architect, that's all I can say. Redux should make writing my hapless React applications more of a pleasure than it already is.